# NSData to NSString truncated - iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have the following code.

```
NSData *pageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
NSString *webpage = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This works fine with most pages but truncates the really long ones, is there a way around this at all?

Comment: Is the truncation because of the length of the returned data (have you outputted both [pageData length] and [webpage length]?), or might it have something to do with character encoding?

Comment: Unsure, PageData is 117638, and webpage is 117637 in length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for (from the `NSString` class reference linked above):

> ```
> stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
> ```
>
> Returns a string created by
>   reading data from a given URL interpreted using a given encoding.
>
> `(id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error`
>
> **Parameters**
>   *url* The URL to read.
>
> *enc* The encoding of the data at url.
>
> *error* If an error occurs, upon returns contains an `NSError` object that
>   describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors,
>   you may pass in `NULL`.
>
> **Return Value**
>   A string created by reading data from *URL* using the
>   encoding, *enc*. If the URL can’t be opened or there is an encoding
>   error, returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this method:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:

If you're just using a synchronous request, this should be fine.

Comment: Hi Dan, 

What section is applicable, I have searched up and down a few times.

Comment: The section I linked to:

    stringWithContentsOfURL: encoding: error

That method will automatically download the url and place the result in a string.